# Taking screenshot in Nexus 4 / Android 5.0.1

Tags: android, screenshot

I am facing an issue with taking screen images (screenshot) in the Nexus 4 running android 5.0.1. I tried pressing the Power button + Volume Down simultaneously, however the volume starts to lower. This feature used to work for me before I had upgraded to 5.0.1. Anyone else is facing an issue this like?

I also wanted to know is there any way I can use the ADT to capture the screenshot? ADT SHELL screerecord can be used to capture the video similarly is there any way I can capture the screenshot?

Regards

Comment: I have Nexus 5 with 5.0.1 update and I can still take screenshots, no problem at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted my phone and the  +  started to take screenshot. This is weird!

But thanks sur007 & Samer. I wanted to know how to take via the studio :).

Answer (score 1):

about the first issue i haven't tried it,
about the second question if you used android studio[image]

the 1st capture pic & 2nd capture videos

Answer (score 1):

You can take a screenshot by following way

(under Window

--> Show View

--> Other...

--> Android

--> Devices).

Click on the device or emulator you want to take a screen shot of, then click the "Screen Capture" button . Occasionally the device won't immediately load the picture; sometimes you have to close/reopen the screen capture window.

This is equivalent to taking a picture via DDMS, but you can do it in Eclipse instead of opening another application.